# Eclipse Incorrectly Claiming I have old Rev of Android SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Just to preface this I have searched high and low on the internet trying to find an answer to this problem and have yet to find one, there have been people with similar problems as me but not quite the same.

I have been trying to set up Eclipse with the Android SDK. I installed Eclipse (Classic) first and edited the .ini file to find the correct javaw.exe file. I tested eclipse and it was working fine. Then I downloaded the android sdk bundle extracted it and used the SDK manager to download the necessary SDK tools (Rev. 21) and the Android 2.33 API. After finishing that, I went back into Eclipse, clicked "Install New Software" and in the "Work With" field typed
"https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/". From there I installed the Developer Tools and NDK plugins and then when finished restarted Eclipse.

Now when I start Eclipse I get the following error 
"This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools revision 21.0.0 rc9 or above.
Current version is 11.0.0
Please update your SDK Tools to latest version"

I know for a fact I have rev 21, it said it when I downloaded it and when I try to go in and update anything whether it be through Eclipse or through the manager it says there are no updates available. I know I have the latest of both the SDK and ADT and I have also tried using the version of eclipse that came with the sdk but that gives me the same issue.
The only other things which seem to set off red flags to me are
1. When the program loads it shows the following message in the console
"[2012-12-01 18:31:48 - Dex Loader] SecurityException: Unable to find field for dex.jar"
2. When I try and open the SDK manager through eclipse it never opens and the console displays the following message
"[2012-12-01 18:37:07 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Expected verb after global parameters but found 'sdk' instead."

I don't know if either of those two have anything to do with what is causing this issue but I hope someone knows what is going on. If someone could help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it, thank you in advance.

(For reference sake, I have been following the instalation instructions in this tutorial
http://youtu.be/31cxmLN09ss)

Comment: What version of java do you have installed? Why did you edit the eclipse ini file? You shouldn't have to edit that to find the java executable

Comment: right now I am using java 1.6.0_27 because that is the version specified in the eclipse read me. Also I had to edit the ini because it was looking for the javaw.exe file in the same directory as eclipse was in unless I added a '-vm' specifying the filepath to the javafile.

Comment: Check out your environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` and make sure it is pointing to the correct install location, the one you just downloaded and extracted.

Comment: I checked my Environment Variables in my Advanced System Settings and did not find an ANDROID_HOME variable, however I went in eclipse and redefined the android sdk location which apparently was on a different android folder for whatever reason which had outdated files in it and I believe now the situation is fixed thank you all very much

Answer (score 4):

When in the SDK Package Manager, try choosing Packages menu -> Reload. Then you should see Android SDK Tools rev21 available and ready to be updated.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for the help! I gave you an Upvote, because you solved my issue! Please give the same answer to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373423/how-to-update-sdk-tools. I will mark your answer as selected

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Glad I was able to help. I have posted my answer there as well. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14376627/1514026)

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. it occurred because once when I was trying to install the adt plugin few months earlier, the location had been saved. I oversaw the old folder location, mistook it for the current updated one and bam! that was all the reason. try to check back the location for tools folder specified.

Answer (score 1):

As follow up to my previous suggestion, better solution is to modify your sdk location in Windows->Preferences->Android to where you install your ADT bundle.  For example, if you install your ADT Bundle under C:\Tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219, enter C:\Tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk.

Doing this also fixes other issue with "Android SDK Manager" not launching from within Eclipse  discussed on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with Eclipse reporting that I have an older sdk even though I have the latest installed by copying the correct sdk version under "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk".  First save existing "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\sdk" to say "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\sdk_old", in case you need to revert.

Answer (score 0):

This (above) is sound advice:  *however I went in eclipse and redefined the android sdk location which apparently was on a different android folder for whatever reason which had outdated files in it and I believe now the situation is fixed* I tried it and it worked for me too. Thanks.